# .Net DirectoryInfo path

Tags: .net

Does anyone know how to set the path for DirectoryInfo when I want to map to a folder named images on webRoot.
/images

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a path relative to your web-app, you'll need to map it with the MapPath(...) method.

In the Page class:

```
string fullyQualifiedFilename = Server.MapPath(relativeFilename);
```

or outside of the page class:

```
string fullyQualifiedFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(relativeFilename);
```

Comment: Yes, thats right the folder is named images, relative to my app it is  ../images
Would I use ../images as the relativeFileName ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Don't worry about the "/", rather use Path.Combine, since it is Platform agnostic and takes care of separators for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
String  virtualPath= "~\\images";
String RealPath=Server.MapPath(virtualPath); //it must be done at web application
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory= new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(RealPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath), "images"));